# Hstacking features somehow causes an extra slowdown in prediction

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, python-3.3

When I use `scipy.sparse.hstack` of some sparse matrices produced by CountVectorizer and the like, and I want to merge them for use in a regression, but somehow they are slower:

- X1 has 10000 features from analyse="char"
- X2 has 10000 features from analyse="word"
- X3 has 20000 features from analyse="char"
- X4 has 20000 features from analyse="word"

You would expect that when you would hstack X1 and X2, it would be around the same speed as X3 or X4 (same number of features). But this appears to be not even close:

> ```
> from scipy.sparse import hstack
> >>> a=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=30).fit(hstack((X1, X2)),y).predict(hstack((t1,t2)))
> time:  57.85
> >>> b=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=30).fit(X1,y).predict(t1)
> time:  6.75
> >>> c=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=30).fit(X2,y).predict(t2)
> time:  7.33
> >>> d=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=30).fit(X3,y).predict(t3)
> time:  6.80
> >>> e=linear_model.Ridge(alpha=30).fit(X4,y).predict(t4)
> time:  11.67
> ```

I at some point even noticed that when I `hstack` only one feature to it, the model also becomes slower. What could cause this, what am I doing wrongly, and of course, what would be an improvement?

### Notable edit:

I would like to introduce a way I thought would solve it, namely constructing a vocabulary and using that to fit:

```
feats = []
method = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word", max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1,3))
method.fit(train["tweet"])
X = method.fit(...)
feats.extend(method.vocabulary_.keys())
method = CountVectorizer(analyzer="char", max_features=10000, ngram_range=(4,4))
method.fit(train["tweet"])
X2 = method.fit(...)
feats.extend(method.vocabulary_.keys())
newm = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=feats)
newm.fit(train["tweet"])
X3 = newm.fit(...)
```

When I fit these, something weird happens to the amount of items stored (I'm not surprised that there are not 20,000 features, as there might be overlap). How can there be so few "ones"?

```
X
<49884x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 927131 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
X2
<49884x10000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3256162 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
X3
<49884x19558 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 593712 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: What type of sparse matricies are they? (e.g. CSR, CRC, BSR, COO, etc, etc)  The performance of an operations is going to depend heavily on the type of sparse structure you use.  There's a good reason that there are so many different types.  Each one has strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: CSR. I assumed only CSR and CRC existed...

Comment: But here it does appear something else changes when CSR's are hstacked?

Answer (score 3):

Hstacking converts it to COO format:

```
>>> hstack((csr_matrix([1]), csr_matrix([2])))
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Maybe do `hstack(...).tocsr()` to check if it speeds it up.

Comment: Since you are part of the scipy development team, do you know why that stacking scheme is used for sparse matrices? hstacking CSC matrices, or vstacking CSR matrices can be done much faster than scipy achieves by concatenating the internal description arrays.

Comment: On the latest model: without tocsr() = 77.83 seconds, with .tocsr() appended it takes 59.12 seconds, so that surely is an improvement.

Comment: The models separately run in 33 and 6 seconds, so I'm hopeful there is something else I'm missing.

Comment: @Jaime: why it works so, is because the original author wrote it so. The original author has not been active in the Scipy project for many years now, so I cannot speak for the reasons why it is at is is. If you want to improve the behavior, patches are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can `hstack` two CSC matrices in a breeze, keeping the output CSC:

```
In [1]: import scipy.sparse as sps

In [2]: a = sps.csc_matrix(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))

In [3]: b = sps.csc_matrix(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))

In [4]: data = np.concatenate((a.data, b.data))

In [5]: indices = np.concatenate((a.indices, b.indices))

In [7]: indptr = np.concatenate((a.indptr[:-1], b.indptr + a.indptr[-1]))


In [10]: c = sps.csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr),
...                         shape = (a.shape[0], a.shape[1]+b.shape[1]))

In [11]: c.A
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

The exact same code, replacing `csc` with `csr` everywhere, will `vstack` two CSR matrices.

You would need to do some timings, but in most cases I believe it is faster to convert both your matrices to CSR or CSC, depending on what stacking you want to do, do the stacking as above, then convert the result to whatever you want, rather than using the built-in stacking functions.

Comment: It would probably be reasonably easy to add fast paths for pure CSR or pure CSC operations into [scipy.sparse.bmat](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L457). I don't necessarily have time to work on this myself in the near future, so if someone else wants to tackle it, [go ahead](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/hacking.html).

Comment: @pv. If my kids spare me some weekend time, I'll definitely look into it myself. Thanks for the great work you guys put into this!

Comment: If you find time, thanks a lot! This sort of speedups are not so easy to find by just looking at the code, but require some real use.

Comment: @pv. I added the fast paths, though not to `bmat`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3057 (Sorry to steal your thunder, @Jaime).